# Random Number Generator Biased To Numbers in the Middle of Range, Java, libGDX

Tags: java, random, libgdx, probability, probability-theory

I am designing a game in libGDX which drops different sized rocks for the user to dodge.

**My Question:** How can I create a method which takes in a low and high int value, and returns a random number. However, I want this random number to be biased toward the middle of the range (similar to a normal distribution).

I would like the method to look something like this:
public int randBiasInt(int low, int high) { }

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29 for an example of how to get a Gaussian/Normal distribution, and as Elliot pointed out, try to implement something using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to the sort of this should work...

```
public int getBiasedInt(int min, int max) {
    int rand = Math.random() * max;
    while (rand < min) {
        rand = Math.random();
    }
    int mid = (max / 2) - (min / 2);
    int halfmid = mid / 2;
    if (rand > mid) {
        rand -= Math.random() * halfmid;
    } else {
        rand += Math.random() * halfmid;
    }
    return rand;
}
```

Not the prettiest, I know.  But it should be acceptable for what you desire...

Comment: Thank you. Much better than what I was doing. I used a random float generator, and then used a series of if-else statements with assigned ranges for probability. This is much better!